# what is the encryption algorithm used by zip files?

Tags: c++, algorithm, encryption, zip

I just want to know the exact formula (or algorithm) used for generating the pseudo random values used in encrypting the zip file. I am trying to create a password hacker(for zip files) and I also require to know how to verify if the random password generated by my program is correct. I have tried searching for an answer to this in Google but I could't find a direct solution.

I am trying to program this zip hacker in c++.

note: by   formula (or algorithm) I meant: key derivation function.
I just want the necessary information as quick as possible, that's why I posted it here!

Comment: I understand that the answer to this question is available in Google along with numerous other information among which just the necessary information needed to locate the encrypted file data, the formula (or algorithm) used in encryption, and the method to verify it is all I need. Thank you in advance! I don't want to know about zip format more than the information necessary to hack the password!

Comment: You know there's many existing programs for this purpose, some of them even written by people who took the time to understand all the issues involved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Different versions of zip-files do it differently, but basically you have an encryption-header specifying what encryption is used according to the zip-file [specification](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT).

For example, the strong encryption header looks like below and specifies the encryption algorithm in the AlgID-field.

```
4.5.12 -Strong Encryption Header (0x0017):

    Value     Size     Description
    -----     ----     -----------
    0x0017    2 bytes  Tag for this "extra" block type
    TSize     2 bytes  Size of data that follows
    Format    2 bytes  Format definition for this record
    AlgID     2 bytes  Encryption algorithm identifier
    Bitlen    2 bytes  Bit length of encryption key
    Flags     2 bytes  Processing flags
    CertData  TSize-8  Certificate decryption extra field data
                       (refer to the explanation for CertData
                        in the section describing the 
                        Certificate Processing Method under 
                        the Strong Encryption Specification)
```

Answer (score 1):

7-zip uses AES-256 encrpytion for 7z/zip archives.([see here](http://7-zip.org/7z.html))

7-Zip also supports encryption with AES-256 algorithm. This algorithm uses cipher key with length of 256 bits. To create that key 7-Zip uses derivation function based on SHA-256 hash algorithm. A key derivation function produces a derived key from text password defined by user. For increasing the cost of exhaustive search for passwords 7-Zip uses big number of iterations to produce cipher key from text password.
Also, keep in mind that Brute force attacks are a waste of time. I won't go into details why, I will instead direct you to Jeff Atwood's blog, he has an [excellent post](http://blog.codinghorror.com/brute-force-key-attacks-are-for-dummies/).